# Is it possible to divide an instruction pipeline into *more* than four subinstructions?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am wondering about something for my programming and computer science class, there is a statement that is supposedly not true, and I am unsure of what the correct answer is. It reads "It is possible to divide an instruction into more than four subinstructions"

can someone please help out and explain what is right here?

I have tried to both find my old notes from class, and search the web, but I cannot really find anything remote to close of what I am asking.

Comment: What would make 4 a magic number?

Comment: In what context?  Some specific microarchitecture?  If you're using a modern x86 from Intel or AMD, the CPU you're using right now has some instructions that decode to dozens of micro-ops.  For example, `xsaveopt` (save the FPU/SIMD state from register to memory) on a Zen 3 decodes to 130 uops.  (https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf / https://uops.info/)

Comment: @ErikEidt: Fun fact: Intel CPUs since P6 (PPro) do have 4 as a magic number: the complex decoder can produce up to 4 uops directly.  Instructions that decode to more uops than that instead get handled by the microcode sequencer, so the decoder just produces a special uop or something that tells the front-end to stream uops from the microcode sequencer once that gets to the front of the issue/rename stage.  So it's not that you can't have more than 4, they just get handled differently.  There's no way in which that statement is true in general, and we don't have context.

Comment: This could be a much better question with some context.  Did it come from a textbook?  Is it talking about a CPU design that's part of the course material or textbook?  There's no limit in general, but with some details about where it's supposed to be not true, it could be answerable and maybe even interesting.  Please [edit] with context; I'd be happy to remove my downvote and maybe even upvote if the question improves with details like that, and I expect others would, too.

Comment: Typical pipelined "simple" in-order RISC processor implementations use 5 pipeline stages (original MIPS, ARM, RISC V, others)  But the term "subinstructions" is less well defined than pipeline stages IMHO, so again I think context is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the (CISC!) VAX-11 polyf instruction, which [evaluates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) a floating-point polynomial given an array of coefficients, order of the polynomial, and value of x.

For high order polynomials, clearly the microcode could
divide the labor into more than four subinstructions.
The app-level assembly programmer still sees the same ABI,
the same number of visible instructions in the object code,
independent of how one hardware model or another
chooses to implement it beneath the hood.

And modern equipment from Intel and competitors has
come a long long way from VAX and Alpha chipsets.
Vectorized instructions might find it convenient
to break the work into more than four pieces.
Even atomic CAS compare-and-swap can be a bit complex.

Comment: Modern short-vector SIMD instructions like x86 SSE/AVX are typically single-uop, or 2 for a CPU that supports AVX with 128-bit execution units like Zen1.  When a vector instruction takes multiple uops, that's only because it does something complicated, like horizontal dot-product (e.g. `dpps`, 8 uops on Zen 3.  https://agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf  / https://uops.info/, or gather loads / scatter stores.)  But yes, atomic CAS is a good example, `lock cmpxchg` is 5 to 6 uops on Zen 3, 10 on Skylake.

Comment: You mentioned Alpha.  But it was totally different from VAX, it was designed from the ground up as a 64-bit RISC, without complex microcoded instructions.  Replacing VAX was a *software* issue.  Alpha is not that different from AArch64, in broad strokes.  Almost all instructions go through the pipeline as one operation.